# Nested query with should sub-condition and "min_should_match"

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to write a query that benefits (higher score) the documents that matches more of the nested items as possible and also has a minimum of these to match.

This is the query I have so far, but its returning 0 matches.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "jobPost.role",
            "score_mode": "sum",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "should": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "role.id": {
                        "value": "12",
                        "boost": 1
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "role.id": {
                        "value": "18",
                        "boost": 1
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "role.id": {
                        "value": "24",
                        "boost": 1
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "role.id": {
                        "value": "28",
                        "boost": 1
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "minimum_number_should_match": "-40%"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

As mentioned, this does not work, however, if I remove the `min_should_match` requirement, it does return matches.

Problem I'm finding is that I need to ensure a certain level of accuracy and I cannot relay on the `min_score` clause.

Any easy solution? I've though about taking the `min_should_match` out to first  `must` and having it at the same level as the `nested` condition; just don't know if thats what I have to do or if theres another solution.

Answer (score 0):

As an initial answer, and awaiting for someone to come with a better (if any) approach:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "jobPost.role",
            "score_mode": "sum",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "should": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "role.id": {
                        "value": "12",
                        "boost": 1
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "role.id": {
                        "value": "18",
                        "boost": 1
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "role.id": {
                        "value": "24",
                        "boost": 1
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "role.id": {
                        "value": "28",
                        "boost": 1
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "role.id": {
                    "value": "12",
                    "boost": 1
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "role.id": {
                    "value": "18",
                    "boost": 1
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "role.id": {
                    "value": "24",
                    "boost": 1
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "role.id": {
                    "value": "28",
                    "boost": 1
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "minimum_number_should_match": "-40%"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This did the job for me, but it feels like duplicating the code is not the best solution.